# Calling a method with another method within another class (calling Method_B within Class_B, with Method_A within Class_A)

Tags: python, python-2.7, maya

I am a Maya user and I am currently writting an Auto-Rig.
I created different Classes for each major tasks of the tool. (ex: Class_UI, Class_Arms_Rig, etc..)

The problem I have is that I can't call a method from "Class_Joints" (the class that will generates every needed Joints) with my "Class_UI"

Here are the codes :

First the Class_UI

```
import sys
sys.path.append('G:\\3D2\\Script\\Auto_Rig')

import Class_Joints
import Class_Arms

import maya.cmds as mc

class Window_UI(object):

# Initializing global variables
def __init__(self):
    
    # Getting acces to the different modules
    self.Arms = Class_Arms.Arms_Rig()
    self.Joints = Class_Joints.Gen_Joints()

    # Create Ui
    self.create_UI()

# Creating the UI
def create_UI(self):
    # Create window
    self.UI = mc.window(title='Auto-Rig Tool', w=(300), h=(350))

    # Main layout
    self.mainLayout = mc.menuBarLayout()

    ### Joints Option ###
    # Create Joints Button
    self.createJointsButton = mc.button(label='Create Joints', command=self.Joints.gen_arms_joints)
    
Window_UI()
mc.showWindow()
```

Then the Class_Joints :

```
import maya.cmds as mc

class Gen_Joints:

# Creating arm Jnts and the list of it
def gen_arms_joints(self):
    
    self.shoulderJnt = mc.joint(absolute=True, position=[5,8,0], n='L_Shoulder_Jnt')
    self.elbowJnt = mc.joint(absolute=True, position=[10,8,-1.5], n='L_Elbow_Jnt')
    self.wristJnt = mc.joint(absolute=True, position=[15,8,0], n='L_Wrist_Jnt')
    self.handcupJnt = mc.joint(absolute=True, position=[18,8,0], n='L_HandCup_Jnt')

    self.jntList = mc.ls(self.shoulderJnt, self.elbowJnt, self.wristJnt, self.handcupJnt)
```

When I run the `Class_UI` Code, the button within the UI is supposed to run the `gen_arms_joints` method within the `Class_Joints`

But I get this error message : `# Error: gen_arms_joints() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given) #`

I know that self is an implicit argument here but I do not know how to avoid this error.

Thank you all for your time.
:D

Cordially, Luca.

Answer (score 1):

Two things i would recommend you do. I dont use Maya but i have built apps with multiple different GUIs.

1. Every GUI I've used when it comes to buttons is the first argument is a reference to self, and then there is usually 1 or 2 more arguments passed in. Some pass the reference to the button itself while others pass a argument that holds event details. My guess is this is what is happening. When you click the button it is passing in an "event" object that hold details about what was clicked and other details.
2. To truly find out what is passed change your function signature to this and see what is logged.

```
def gen_arms_joints(self, mystery_second_arg):
    print(type(mystery_second_arg), mystery_second_arg)

    self.shoulderJnt = mc.joint(absolute=True, position=[5,8,0], n='L_Shoulder_Jnt')
    self.elbowJnt = mc.joint(absolute=True, position=[10,8,-1.5], n='L_Elbow_Jnt')
    self.wristJnt = mc.joint(absolute=True, position=[15,8,0], n='L_Wrist_Jnt')
    self.handcupJnt = mc.joint(absolute=True, position=[18,8,0], n='L_HandCup_Jnt')
    self.jntList = mc.ls(self.shoulderJnt, self.elbowJnt, self.wristJnt, self.handcupJnt)
```

Comment: I tried to add this 'mystery_second_arg' but it's not different from before, I still got the same error message `# Error: gen_arms_joints() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given) # `

Comment: This is exactly what `mc.button` does and why it's causing an error. Since you're importing the module don't forget to `reload` it first so it runs the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that in the `__init__()` call of the `Class_UI`, you have defined the wrong class call for the actual function `gen_arm_joints(self)`, it should be: `self.Joints = Gen_Joints()`, seems like you have different `import classNames` but in the code you have called the class as `Gen_Joints`. You can't pass in two `self` classes references i.e the error traceback.

You will have to fix the `import` class to `import Gen_Joints`.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand.
I will explain what I wanted to do with these "import things"

First I import the Module called "Class_Joints"
Then within the  __init__()  I associate
 >self.Joints = Class_Joints.Gen_Joints()           which correspond to self.Joints = ModuleName.ClassName()


I understood from your answer that I need to import my module "Class_Joints" and then within the __init__() part, write self.joints = Gen_Joints(), but that can't be done, the class Gen_Joints, won't be find right ?

This is what I tried and it did'nt worked

Comment: It should be able to find the `self.Joints = Gen_Joints()`. I am not sure if the code is missing more components to this problem, but it seems like that should do the trick. and the args call within the function call you will do: `self.createJointsButton = (....,command = self.Joints.gen_arms_joints)`.

Answer (score 0):

@FishingCode

Look out what I tried based on what you told me :

```
import sys
sys.path.append('G:\\3D2\\Script\\Auto_Rig')

import Class_Joints
import Class_Arms

import maya.cmds as mc

class Window_UI(object):

    # Initializing global variables
    def __init__(self):
    
        # Getting acces to the different modules
        self.Arms = Class_Arms.Arms_Rig()
        self.Joints = Gen_Joints()

        # Create Ui
        self.create_UI()

    # Creating the UI
    def create_UI(self):
        # Create window
        self.UI = mc.window(title='Auto-Rig Tool', w=(300), h=(350))

        # Main layout
        self.mainLayout = mc.menuBarLayout()

        # Create Joints Button
        self.createJointsButton = mc.button(label='Create Joints', command=self.Joints.gen_arms_joints)

#show window
Window_UI()
mc.showWindow()
```

It's exactly what I have on Visual Studio Code

```
    import maya.cmds as mc

class Gen_Joints:

    # Creating arm Jnts and the list of it
    def gen_arms_joints(self):
        
        self.shoulderJnt = mc.joint(absolute=True, position=[5,8,0], n='L_Shoulder_Jnt')
        self.elbowJnt = mc.joint(absolute=True, position=[10,8,-1.5], n='L_Elbow_Jnt')
        self.wristJnt = mc.joint(absolute=True, position=[15,8,0], n='L_Wrist_Jnt')
        self.handcupJnt = mc.joint(absolute=True, position=[18,8,0], n='L_HandCup_Jnt')

        self.jntList = mc.ls(self.shoulderJnt, self.elbowJnt, self.wristJnt, self.handcupJnt)
```

VS Code tells me `Undefined variable 'Gen_Joints'`
And within maya I get `# Error: NameError: file <maya console> line 16: global name 'Gen_Joints' is not defined #`

Comment: Why are you doing `import Class_Joints`? Where else is that *defined*.

Comment: I am doing this to have access to the method `gen_arms_joints` which is within this module. Class_Joints is the Module containing the `Gen_Joints` Class, containning the `gen_arms_joints` method, that I need to call when I press the "Create Joints" Button, in the second module Class_UI.

Comment: Gotcha. That module is not visible anywhere, thus my comment. Keep at it, you maybe close.

Answer (score 0):

`mc.button` passes on an extra `boolean` value to the method, so since that's not defined in `gen_arms_joints` it throws that error and says it's the wrong number of arguments.

So simply add an extra parameter and it'll fix it:
`def gen_arms_joints(self, extra_param):`

Or better yet use `*args` instead to be a bit more generic:
`def gen_arms_joints(self, *args):`

It's honestly kind of sneaky because it's not really stated in the documentation, but you can see it being used in [the example at the bottom of the page](http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/button.html).